# In Struts 2.5.14 I am not able to add new action, only action I can add is hello in every package of struts.xml

Tags: java, struts2, tiles2

Below is the content of struts.xml, I am using tiles also, adding action with name other than hello is not working.  using tomcat
7.0.88, and java 8

- `..\view\contracts` is not working
- `..\home\hello`  is working
- `..\view\hello`  is working**

**struts.xml:**

```
<struts>
  <package name="home" namespace="/home" extends="struts-default">
    <result-types>
      <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
    </result-types>

    <action name="hello" class="action.HelloWorldAction" method="execute">
      <result type="tiles">menu</result>
    </action>
    <action name="contracts" class="action.ViewContractsAction" method="contracts">
      <result type="tiles">hello</result>
    </action>
  </package>

  <package name="view" namespace="/view" extends="struts-default">
    <result-types>
      <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
    </result-types>
    <action name="hello" class="action.ViewContractsAction" method="execute">
      <result type="tiles">contracts</result>
    </action>
    <action name="contracts" class="action.ViewContractsAction" method="contracts">
      <result type="tiles">contracts</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

**Error log:**

```
    There is no Action mapped for action name contracts. - [unknown location]
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:195)        org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:57)        org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:32)        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:60)org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:79)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:141)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Pro
```

Comment: I removed hello action from both package in  struts.xml still ..\home\hello ..\home\hello are working

Comment: What specific URL are you trying to hit? What does the *browser* think you're trying to hit? E.g., show us the URL you're typing into the URL bar.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave for reply, It got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this.
Just remove the default package from struts.xml
remove the home package and hello action struts.xml.

I tried reverting this changes to see if the proble is still because of this, and I found the same error again, which says above change is the solution.